# TFLite Converter: RandomStandardNormal implemented for keras model, but not for pure TensorFlow model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

**Task**

I have two models which should be equivalent. The first one is built with keras, the second one with tensorflow. Both variational autoencoders use the `tf.random.normal` method in their model. Also, they produce similar results. Everything is tested with the nightly build (1.15).

The confusion comes when I try to convert them into a tensorflow lite model with post-training quantization. I use the same command for both models:

```
converter = tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter... # from respective save file
converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset_gen
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]

tflite_model = converter.convert()
open('vae.tflite', 'wb').write(tflite_model)
```

**Error**

For the keras model, everything goes well and I end up with a working tflite model. However, if I try to do this with the tensorflow version, I run into an error stating that `RandomStandardNormal` is not implemented:

> Some of the operators in the model are not supported by the standard
>   TensorFlow Lite runtime. If those are native TensorFlow operators, you
>   might be able to use the extended runtime by passing
>   --enable_select_tf_ops, or by setting target_ops=TFLITE_BUILTINS,SELECT_TF_OPS when calling
>   tf.lite.TFLiteConverter(). Otherwise, if you have a custom
>   implementation for them you can disable this error with
>   --allow_custom_ops, or by setting allow_custom_ops=True when calling tf.lite.TFLiteConverter(). Here is a list of builtin operators you are
>   using: ADD, EXP, FULLY_CONNECTED, LEAKY_RELU, LOG, MUL. Here is a list
>   of operators for which you will need custom implementations:
>   RandomStandardNormal.

**Question**

This does not make sense to me because obviously this is already working with keras. Does keras know something that I have to tell my tensorflow model explicitly?

**MODELS**

tensorflow

```
fc_layer = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense

# inputs have shape (90,)
x = tf.identity(inputs, name='x')

# encoder
outputs = fc_layer(x, 40, activation=leaky_relu)

self.z_mu = fc_layer(outputs, 10, activation=None)
self.z_sigma = fc_layer(outputs, 10, activation=softplus)

# latent space
eps = tf.random.normal(shape=tf.shape((10,)), mean=0, stddev=1, dtype=tf.float32)
outputs = self.z_mu + eps * self.z_sigma

# decoder
outputs = fc_layer(outputs, 40, activation=leaky_relu)

# prediction
x_decoded = fc_layer(outputs, 90, activation=None)
```

keras

```
x = keras.layers.Input(shape=(90,))

h = keras.layers.Dense(40, activation=leakyrelu)(x)

z_mu = keras.layers.Dense(10)(h)
z_sigma = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=softplus)(h)

eps = tf.random.normal(shape=tf.shape((10,)), mean=0, stddev=1, dtype=tf.float32)
z = z_mu + eps * z_sigma

h_decoded = keras.layers.Dense(40, activation=leakyrelu)(z)
x_decoded = keras.layers.Dense(90)(h_decoded)

train_model = keras.models.Model(x, x_decoded)
```

Comment: I have opened a github issue for this, which provides all the code for testing: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32206

Answer (score 0):

!pip install tensorflow==1.15

```
import tensorflow as tf
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file('model.h5') 
converter.allow_custom_ops = True
tfmodel = converter.convert() 
open ("model.tflite" , "wb") .write(tfmodel)
```